# Onclick Listener On Recycler View Has to Open Different activities

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, adapter, onclicklistener

This is my adapter class that contains my onClick listener where I want it to open various activities depending on the item clicked in the recycler view. I cant seem to implement a method that would do the job.

```
 //DATA BOUND TO VIEWS
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(MyHolder holder, int position) {
    
            //BIND DATA
            holder.ProductCategory.setText(products.get(position).getProductCategory());
            holder.ProductImage.setImageResource(products.get(position).getProductImage());
    
            //IMPLEMENT CLICK LISTENER
            holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(View v, int pos) {
                    
                //i get errors when i try to implement in this method
    
                }
            });
    
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set click listener to `itemView` of your holder class as :

```
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Place your logic to open diffrent activity based on holder.getAdapterPosition()
            }
        });
```

And put your activity opening logic inside onClick() method. use `holder.getAdapterPosition()` for postion of current view

Answer (score 0):

Actually, i solved the problem by just adding "if else" statements that specified which action should be taken when an item in the recycler view is click based on its position on the list.

```
//DATA BOUND TO VIEWS
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyHolder holder, int position) {

        //BIND DATA
        holder.ProductCategory.setText(products.get(position).getProductCategory());
        holder.ProductImage.setImageResource(products.get(position).getProductImage());

        //IMPLEMENT CLICK LISTENER


        holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View v, int pos) {


                // this is the solution
                if(position == 0){
                    //first item clicked
                    Intent intent = new Intent(c, CartWeb.class);// what happens when an 
                                                                 // item is clicked
                    c.startActivity(intent);

                }else if(position == 1){
                    //second item clicked
                    Intent intent = new Intent(c,Options.class);
                    c.startActivity(intent);

                }

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

implement click listener in onCreateVHolder

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                        // here implement which you want onItem click
                    }
            }
        });
```